# Click on image trigger other image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using Materialize design. I want to open other image after click on another image.

CODE:

```
<img id="prod-big-image" 
    class="materialboxed" style="width:100%;" 
    src="<catalog:ProductImageUrl  
    pictureId="${product.productPictureMappings[0].pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" 
    useCase="descriptionPageBig"/>" 
                             alt="buy ${product.name}" title="${product.name}">
<div class="center-align">
    <c:forEach items="${product.productPictureMappings}" var="pic" varStatus="loopStatus">
        <a href="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" 
           productName="${product.name}" useCase="zoom"/>">
            <img class="abc" class="prod-zoom-img" 
                data-bigimgurl="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="descriptionPageBig"/>" 
                width="60"  src="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="modal-giftbox"/>" 
               alt="view ${product.name}" title="${product.name}">
        </a>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

SCREEN SHOT:
[image]

Small images should not clickable. If user click on small images then big image trigger, place of small images.

Comment: remove Images first..

Answer (score 0):

I got a answer, Remove anchor tag link.

CODE:

```
<img id="prod-big-image" class="materialboxed n" style="width:100%;" src="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${product.productPictureMappings[0].pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="descriptionPageBig"/>" 
                             alt="buy ${product.name}" title="${product.name}">
                        <div class="center-align">
                            <c:forEach items="${product.productPictureMappings}" var="pic" varStatus="loopStatus">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="prod-zoom-img materialboxed abc" data-bigimgurl="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="descriptionPageBig"/>" 
                                         width="60"  src="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="modal-giftbox"/>" alt="view ${product.name}" title="${product.name}"/>
                              </a>
                            </c:forEach>
                      </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.abc').click(function(){        
            $('.n').trigger('click');
        });
```

If you are taking image with anchor tag link then it will first redirect to an image. Then Remove anchor tag link.